# Trouble with understanding how RabbitMQ can be used

Tags: python, rabbitmq

i'm currently working on a Python web app that needs to implement RabbitMQ.
The app is structured like that :

1. The client connects to a HTTP server
2. His connexion is send to a message queue that is connected to the main service of my app
3. the main service receive the message and give the user his information

I understand how to make work RabbitMq using the documentation and tutorial on the website but I have trouble seeing how can it work with real tasks like displaying a web page or printing a file ? How does my service connected to the message queue will read the message received and say : "oh, i'm gonna display this webpage".

Sorry if this is confusing, if you need further explanations on what i'm trying to get, just tell me.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Why does your Python web app _need_ to use RabbitMQ, to display a web site? This sounds like a straightforward goal (display a web site) made much more complicated by trying to use a tool designed for a completely different purpose. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @andrewjames : 
I'm doing a web-app with Flask that manage VM Virtualization so that the user can create, update and launch a VM with the app. RabbitMQ is used here to avoid  that the server where the app is hosted don't support all the possible connections and can do each task asked by the user one by one by dispatching them in message queues solely for each task.

What I would like to know is how can my task app (lets say Create a VM) read the queue and proceeds to create a VM ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. You can [edit] the question and add your notes there.

Answer (score 0):

`RabbitMq` can be good to send message to service which can execute long running process - ie download big file, generate complex animation. Web server can't (or shoudn't) execute long running process.

Web page sends message to `RabbitMq` (ie. with parameters for long running process) and get unique number. When service has free worker then it checks if there is new message in queue, get it (with unique number) and start worker. When worker finish job then service send result to `RabbitMQ` with the same uniqe number.

At the same time web page uses JavaScript to run loop which periodically check in `RabbitMQ` if there is result with this unique number. If there is no result then it may display `progressbar`, if there is result then it may display this result.

---

Example: [Celery - Distributed Task Queue](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html).

`Celery` can use `RabbitMQ` to communicate with `Django` or `Flask`.
(but it can use other modules ie. `Redis`)

[Using Celery with Django](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

[Flask - Celery Background Tasks](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/celery/)

---

From [Celery repo](https://github.com/celery/celery)

```
Celery is usually used with a message broker to send and receive messages. 
The RabbitMQ, Redis transports are feature complete, but there's also 
experimental support for a myriad of other solutions, including using 
SQLite for local development.
```